# 'if' use for mean of consecutive trials based on a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have this dataset below and i want to calculate the `mean(SACCADIC_RT)` for the 5 consecutive `HITS` that precede one commission error, per `ID` and `CONDITION`.

So far, i have tried:

```
Data[, roll := Reduce('+', shift(HIT, 0:4)), by =list(ID, CONDITION)]

if (Data $roll == 5 & Data$COMISSION_ERROR[c(which(Data$roll == 5) +1), ] == 1)
 A<-  with(Data, mean(SACCADIC_RT[roll ==5]), by =list(ID, CONDITION))
```

This is not right though. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

An example of how my Data look like:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X..TRIAL.. = c(183L, 54L, 26L, 3L, 100L, 11L, 52L, 8L, 10L, 21L, 32L, 2L, 13L, 87L, 95L, 111L, 28L, 65L, 40L, 19L, 28L, 45L, 197L, 115L, 65L, 24L, 1L, 77L, 90L, 89L, 104L, 116L, 29L, 41L), TRIAL_TYPE. = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("go", "nogo"), class = "factor"), CONDITION = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("square_1", "square_2"), class = "factor"), X..COMMISSION_ERROR = c(1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L), X..HITS. = c(-1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L), SACCADIC_RT = c(175L, 259L, 365L, 346L, 287L, 164L, 244L, 223L, 183L, 234L, 221L, 183L, -1L, 228L, 274L, 305L, 309L, -1L, 199L, 207L, 257L, 169L, 350L, 321L, 298L, -1L, 183L, 225L, 305L, 210L, 199L, 175L, 99L, 104L)), .Names = c("ID", "X..TRIAL..", "TRIAL_TYPE.", "CONDITION", "X..COMMISSION_ERROR", "X..HITS.", "SACCADIC_RT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

An example of the output is:

```
    ID | CONDITION |  x
    1    square_1      209.6
    2    square_2      222.8
```

@rconradin

Comment: Are you using any additional packages?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: Did you `setkey` before calculating? and what is an error in this dataset?

Comment: Before calculating i did: `Data <- data.table(Data)`  The error is `COMISSION_ERROR==1` @akash87

Comment: I am not using any additional packages apart from data.table. @jogo. Any thoughts on how to improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `data.table` and `zoo` packages.

```
require(data.table); require(zoo)
data[  , A := rollmeanr(SACCADIC_RT, k = 5, fill = NA)][
      roll == 5 & lead(COMMISSION_ERROR) == 1]
```

`rollmeanr` comes from the `zoo` package.

Also, for completeness, if you only want the three column specified, you can use

```
data[  , A := rollmeanr(SACCADIC_RT, k = 5, fill = NA)][
      roll == 5 & lead(COMMISSION_ERROR) == 1, .(ID, CONDITION, A)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually getting the error` Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "lead"` and i did `require(zoo)` . Is it possible to create a new subset of data with the new column per `ID` and `CONDITION` instead of adding the column to the existing data.table? I tried to  used `lag` instead and it seems that it calculates the `mean(SACCADIC_RT)` for every 5 consecutive HITS but not when the next trial is a `COMISSION_ERROR ==1`

Comment: I'm sorry `lead` and `lag` are part of `dplyr`. The equivalent in `data.table` is actually `shift`.

Comment: So i did try `Data[, roll := Reduce('+', shift(HIT, 0:4)), by =list(ID, CONDITION)]`
`Data[  , A := rollmeanr(SACCADIC_RT, k = 5, fill = NA)][
      roll == 5 & shift(COMMISSION_ERROR) == 1], .(ID, CONDITION, A)]` and it gives me `NAs` in the `A` column.

Comment: What value do you want in `A`?

Comment: Is there a way to extract, only the values from `A` per `ID` and `CONDITION` that i am interested? At the moment the `A` column saves the `rollmeanr` for every 5 `HITS` but doesn't give only those that precede a commission error. I want to subset/aggregate only those trials though

Comment: Yes there is. Using `data.table`, prior to the first comma, you can specify what row(s) you are interested.